# Replication, how to encrypt a column at subscription side and keep publication side non-encrypt?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, database-replication

In replication case. Instance B pull some tables from instance A(for other users). I want to encrypt a column of one table in instance B (But don't want to encrypt the original table at instance A). How can I make this work?
When I try to encrypt the column. It will show 'will change the collation'. And after this, the replication does not work anymore:(﻿
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like create an indexed view at the publisher that is just the primary key columns from the base table plus the encrypted column and then replicate the view. Then, on the subscriber side you can piece it all back together with a view. Kind of hacky, but it'll do.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply. But in my case, I don't want to encrypt the column at the Publisher (It's open for the use at instance A). But we can't encrypt the column of the view, right? We can replicate the view if it has the primary key, but if we can't encrypt the column of the view. How can we encrypt the column alone on the subscriber side?

Comment: My suggestion is to create another column that is the encrypted value. What popped into my head was a view that's something like `select ID, encrypt(yourColumn) from yourTable` and then replicate that view, but you could just as easily add the column in the same table. Either way, you'd want to set the table to not replicate the original (plaintext) column.